# How do you prevent a javascript redirect from exiting fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect to a new url using javascript within an already fullscreen mode but the redirect currenlt exits fullscreen mode which I dont want. Am I using the wrong JS code?

```
 window.location.href = demo_url;
```

or

```
 window.location = demo_url;
```

Comment: You're simply changing the URL.  You can't do it any simpler than that!  If it's exiting fullscreen mode, I have to imagine it's a browser feature -- probably for some security reason.  If you have a link on your page that goes to the demo_url instead of changing it with JS, does it exit fullscreen mode?

Comment: I fear you might be right with the security feature suggestion. All the links on the page work fine and stay in fullscreen. Its just the JS redirect that triggers it to exit (even though its the same domain). FYI, i'm using Chrome and it only has to work in the latest version of chrome, no other browsers.

Comment: Try this "hack" to see if it works: `<form method="get" action="YOUR DEMO URL" id="autopost"></form>` then instead of setting location `$('#autopost').submit()` (you can use straight JS if you don't have jquery).  Basically, creating a form, then using JS to submit the form, which will change the URL.  Worth a shot!

Comment: Damn it, I thought you had just made my decade with such a cunning hack, but sadly it doesn't work :-( And also, my earlier comment re other links working wasnt true (clicking links also closes the fullscreen mode), my mistake, sorry.

Comment: OK, and wierldy I've just discovered that its because i'm launching fullscreen mode programmatically - if you use F11 to go fullscreen, the JS redirect/form submit doesnt exit full screen mode. Hmmmmm.

Comment: OK, i've solved it - its related to the answer I added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I was going about this the wrong way - if you using a Chrome extension and want full screen mode as I was, then you can just use the following:

```
 chrome.windows.getCurrent(null, function(window) {
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, {state: "fullscreen"});
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the document address, the browser will always exit full screen mode.

The only thing you could do to get the same visual result is to present the 'new' page inside an iframe that has 100% height and width.

Comment: That's too bad with todays javascript frameworks / HTML5 History that allow you to navigate a site without actually reloading the page.