# jquery - keep in fullscreen when clicking to an internal link

Tags: jquery, html, click, fullscreen

I have a problem with html5 fullscreen api. I'm using the fullscreen jquery api (downloaded from here - https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin ) that works fine until user clicks to a link.

I want to solve this to keep user in fullscreen mode as it wont turn it off. It's okay to save fullscreen state it cookie, its done but when user clicks on a link it always destroys.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607582/how-do-you-prevent-a-javascript-redirect-from-exiting-fullscreen-mode

Comment: I've found this thread before I posted mine but there were no crossbrowser solution for this problem.